# The sentry beyond heaven and hell

Tags: science-based, technology, weapons, mythology

Set in 29th century a team of scientists hunting for the different types of higgs boson, an elementary particle responsible for giving some particles their mass, millions of billions of micro black-holes sporadically come in and out of existence in the searing tiny region of space where 2 beams of relativistic heavy ions traveling in opposite directions collided with each other inside the bubble chamber located along a Dyson's Ring 4, also nicknamed "Spear of Destiny" orbiting our Sun.

Prometheus, a titan whom according to legend was spared by Zeus in Greek Mythology has been waiting for this moment to seek the Elysium, a sacred place in which her siblings are locked up. According to her reliable Intel one has to wait for a tartarus to form, and then use the Excalibur, the only key in the universe capable of prying open tartarus. Tartarus is simply a micro black hole but forms when millions of them merged into one and lasts longer than usual, Prometheus teleported inside the bubble chamber and inserted Excalibur into the tartarus, she is capable of moving and thinking at speed hundreds of thousands time faster than any human.

The entrance to Elysium is opened at last, before Prometheus can enter a blinding light flashed and she was mortally wounded by an intense pulse of high energy Gamma Ray Burst fired from a towering entity, Zeus order a sophisticated terminator series T-1000B nicknamed "Thunderbolt Buster" to guard the holy place. However Kronus tears Thunderbolt into two with his bare hands and feeds Prometheus "Eilxir", a pill where the Chinese believes could grant user immortality but it was already too late and at this time the angry Titan roars...

My question is how can I fire a single shot equivalent to a GRB? Kindly apply magic sparingly and my story is actually intended for teens as there are no adult themes yet.

Comment: Given all that you have in your story line, can you not say that you fire a single shot "because you can?"  Is the intended audience going to have a sufficiently deep scientific background as to delve into how a GRB can be created?  I admit, even as a science loving adult, I stopped trying to think of this as science based the instant you brought in a titan and teleportation into the mix.

Comment: @Cort Ammon there is always a distinction between what's science and what's not however at times science is weirder than fiction and I like to prove it with all your help of course.

Comment: In that case, we probably should know more about the science of the other parts.  What scientific explanation do you have in place for teleportation?  It might be useful for deciding on an explanation of the GRB.  And are humans aware of the existence of titans, Excalibur, and tartarus when the scene unfolds?  Also, how does Excalibur work, given that there is no known scientific method of bringing something back out of a black hole?

Comment: @Cort Ammon thanks for reminding me that's will be for another questions, for my plot a group of cybernetic augmented psychics know about the incident and decided to team with 1 of the prime evil, Mephisto the demon lord of hell which secretly give Excalibur to Prometheus while disguising as an holographic A.I. alright this is hard please answer my question I'm out of juice right now. Excalibur is actually an ancient relic misplaced by extinct alien species using sophisticated nanotechnology to magnetically bind the exotic particles inside Excalibur the firmware is using "Mjolnir"...

Comment: Bubble chamber? I think the idea is unusable in that enwrgy regime and does not give a full census of the collision, unlike modern layers of solid-state sensors.  Preschoolers, really?  Why wait 'till, the 29th century to do stuff being worked on now? Could be that the *heaviest* particles are finally getting experiments with the availability of higher energy, though they were known since 2050.

Comment: @JDlugosz humanity splits into 2 fractions 1 allied with demon while the other being more scientific. A series of civil wars occurs throught the solar systems and finally peace arrive and research on sub atomic physics gets sufficient budget to start. Meanwhile the terrorists now exiled to Oort Clouds are planning to use "Purgatory" and "Genesis" abandoned alien spaceships successfully reverse engineered to destroy the world... ok no more juice so answer please I beg all of u...

Comment: "Preschooler or teens"? That's a pretty big difference. Or did you mean "pre-teens or teens"?

Comment: Be sure to include Donald Duck and SpongeBob characters. That will fit in with your intended audience.  I think your ideas is not suitable for [tag:science-based], and answers in that vein will not fit in with your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can relax the goal from "Gamma Ray Burst" to merely "a large burst of gamma rays," I could see a staff that could generate such a force.

The black holes, with just the few details as written, could not be the entrance to Tartarus.  They are freshly minted black holes with no connection to any other place in spacetime; they are just black holes.  However, if one were to be created with a sufficient gravitational pull, it might bend spacetime sufficient to intersect with Tartarus, creating an Einstein-Rosen bridge to Tartarus.  If one such bridge was created, it would be untraversable - the forces would rip things apart.  All Einstein-Rosen bridges are believed to be untraversable.  It is believed that we need something known as negative matter, matter with negative mass, to "stabilize" the wormhole to allow travel.  We have never seen any hints that such material exists, but perhaps Excalibur could be made of such material.

If we have decided that negative matter exists in this story universe, then it is absolutely reasonable to assume that large quantities of anti-matter could be made and contained.  Perhaps the "towering entity" that fires the gamma rays was given a treasure staff with a few kilograms of antimatter held in suspension, so that on command it could be annihilated.  Matter/anti-matter annihilation generates very high energy gamma rays.  You could run numbers on how much energy you want to see to determine the mass of anti-matter that such a treasure staff must contain.

Comment: There are hints that negative energy densities are possible, see the [Casimir effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect), which was mentioned on the 2nd page of the [original paper on traversable wormholes](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/9262/1/MORprl88.pdf). It's still unclear whether this effect would violate the right combo of "energy conditions" in general relativity to allow for traversable wormholes, see the ["Raychaudhuri's theorem and exotic matter" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Raychaudhuri.27s_theorem_and_exotic_matter) of wikipedia's wormhole article.

Answer (score 0):

A [Gamma ray Laser](http://www.livescience.com/45445-building-a-gamma-ray-laser.html)!

Apparently it is already theorized to be possible to build with "an exotic hybrid of matter and antimatter"  So you're powerful robot just needs a big laser!  Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

From what [Berkeley lets us know](http://w.astro.berkeley.edu/research/grbs/grbinfo.html) about gamma ray bursts, we aren't exactly sure where GRBs come from. One theory is that two massive stellar objects collide with each other, and this one appears to have the [best evidence](http://spaceref.com/astronomy/nasa-researchers-solve-the-mystery-of-the-origin-of-short-gamma-ray-bursts.html).

[Micro black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole) aren't exactly massive, but they are massive for their size. Since your audience isn't intended to be the highly scientific community, you can use a little handwave to declare that the collision of two micro black holes produces a GRB.

Micro black holes are also associated with space dimension theories. Your sentry could be a living entity that looks like a supermassive star and serves as the sun for the Tartarus in the alternate dimension. This stellar entity could then fire huge amounts of energy in GRBs at anyone who opens the dimension.

Comment: Note that there are different kinds of GRB in two major categories.  There are various causes to catalog, not just one thing.

Comment: @JDługosz The first link has several theories. I merely picked the one I felt most applicable to this question.